# Why does pressing Alt+B make everything disappear?

Tags: edit-mode, selection-tools

I'm trying to clip an area with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and when I do, my whole mesh disappears until I <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> again. I can't find any evidence of this happening to anyone else. I tried going back to an earlier save, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> works fine, make some changes, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> again and it's broken again.

Anyone know what the problem might be?